What about people like me who know God exists but don't have faith in God?
The difference between a person like me who knows that God exists and a person who believes that God exists is personal experience.
For example I have experienced events in my life where mystical beings have spied on me and taken information to a remote human being in control of those beings. I applied my reasoning and logic proved that the only way someone in the US can know what I am doing in Israel is through divination or necromancy, and that otherwise a normal person wouldn't. This is how I arrived at the knowledge that mystical beings indeed exist and are able to do things normal humans wouldn't be able to.

Editor's note: Assume the reasoning above is valid for the sake of answering the question.

The Bible says that without faith we do not please God
Hebrew 11:6

And without faith it is impossible to please God," meaning that in order to be pleasing to God, one must have faith in Him

Does that mean a person who knows instead of believes is in violation of that verse?

While this question might be entirely on personal opinion, I believe the question can be answered within doctrine and scriptures. I hope this remains open and I will attempt to answer when I can.

I don't see that your claims prove knowledge of God. Maybe the person works at the CIA and you're on a watchlist. Maybe they're just a really good guesser. Maybe telepathy is real but God isn't. Maybe you put more information on social media than you realize. What you know is the fact that the person knows things you think they shouldn't. Your conclusion that this must be due to mystical beings and that this proves the existence of God is belief. It may be a rational, factually-based belief, but I'll maintain that Christianity is factually-based and rational.

@user111403 How does that improve the question? Pretend it is 1000 years ago. Or just answer assuming the example is valid. They didn't ask about the example. It would be just as valid if the example was "and then a vision told me which next 50 stars would go super nova in which order"

Hey, I edited your question. Please double check that I have remained true to your intent. I believe I've made it possible for people to answer the question without getting distracted by details. I also tried to make the english more natural.

@Wyrsa since you ask, I do think the question would be improved by simply removing the invalid, personal example and framing it more generically. It is more an objection to the framing than to the content of the question itself, which can be answered (and I upvoted your answer, FWIW)

@user111403 I didn't want to remove the person's personal reason. But if they would edit it, that would be okay. That is why I simply put a note instead. And thanks for the upvote. :)

I wish to add onto Wyrsa's answer with the observation that, even in the presence of compelling rational evidence, it is still entirely possible (if not likely) for man to reject God. The following passage is the clearest example that comes to mind:

19 “There was a rich man who was dressed in purple and fine linen and lived in luxury every day. 20 At his gate was laid a beggar named Lazarus, covered with sores 21 and longing to eat what fell from the rich man’s table. Even the dogs came and licked his sores.
22 “The time came when the beggar died and the angels carried him to Abraham’s side. The rich man also died and was buried. 23 In Hades, where he was in torment, he looked up and saw Abraham far away, with Lazarus by his side. 24 So he called to him, ‘Father Abraham, have pity on me and send Lazarus to dip the tip of his finger in water and cool my tongue, because I am in agony in this fire.’
25 “But Abraham replied, ‘Son, remember that in your lifetime you received your good things, while Lazarus received bad things, but now he is comforted here and you are in agony. 26 And besides all this, between us and you a great chasm has been set in place, so that those who want to go from here to you cannot, nor can anyone cross over from there to us.’
27 “He answered, ‘Then I beg you, father, send Lazarus to my family, 28 for I have five brothers. Let him warn them, so that they will not also come to this place of torment.’
29 “Abraham replied, ‘They have Moses and the Prophets; let them listen to them.’
30 “‘No, father Abraham,’ he said, ‘but if someone from the dead goes to them, they will repent.’
31 “He said to him, ‘If they do not listen to Moses and the Prophets, they will not be convinced even if someone rises from the dead.’”
— Luke 16:19–31, NIV (emphasis mine)

Recall also how the Pharisees witnessed a miracle being performed before their very eyes, and immediately "plotted to kill Jesus" instead of believing (Matthew 12:14). See also the guards at Jesus' tomb, who saw something undeniably supernatural and yet chose to follow the instructions of the unbelieving authorities.
Personally, I think Jesus' ministry on earth allows us to safely draw the conclusion that, for many, their lack of faith is not actually a rational decision. Instead, they would reject any signs given to them, no matter how compelling. Especially in today's culture of scientism, one can always take the out of "my senses might have decieved me", "perhaps all the eyewitness testimonies could be a collective hallucination", and so on. To respond to evidence with belief is itself an act of obedience. (That is, as long as the belief is total, and not merely something like: "Well, I guess there's a high probability Christianity is true, so I'll follow it until new evidence emerges and I change my mind.")

Just like fallen angels could see him and his throne but still chose to rebel. Created beings always struggle with this, even Adam and Eve heard the voice of God in the garden every day but still chose to rebel.

I sent you an email, those people would know what I would do in my room and would tell me the next morning when I went to school, how they acquired this knowledge is still a mystery to me but some prophets exposed them. The truth always comes out

James 2:19 says "You believe that there is one God. Good! Even the demons believe that – and shudder." Believing is not the same as having faith/being faithful.
Faith, according to the writer to the Hebrews, is trust, obedience and action in its very essence. It isn't at all a vague feeling that something might be/is probably true, or even worse, "believing in something you just know ain't true."
So I think you are making a mistake by associating mere belief with faith, and elevating "knowing" to a higher level.

Ye have to believe in things you cannot see, that is faith

Your point? The devils also have knowledge, so we have to believe for without faith it's impossible to please God

In your question you seemed use "belief" and "faith" interchangeably, and to imply that knowing is a result of proof/evidence, whereas belief/faith is not. I would strongly contest that.

I observed something strange and I had to draw conclusions , God gave me that IQ to question why this when it should be this way to arrive at the knowledge of the truth

@SoFewAgainstSoMany, faith isn't believing that God exists despite a lack of certain knowledge. Faith is trust; it is having confidence in God's promises and believing that those promises apply to one's self. Thus, having certain knowledge of God's existence is not incompatible with having faith.

@Matthew, if God exists then all his promises are also true, of course he gets to keep his promises but He has a way of revealing Himself to everyone, mine was through rationality on people who seemed to acquire knowledge about me in a way that beats logic

@SoFewAgainstSoMany, I once compared Christianity to a bowl of 'God's Presence: Admit One' tickets. Saying "of course God keeps His promises" is like saying "of course the tickets are legit". You still have to believe that actually taking a ticket does something for you; that is faith. (For that matter, I think there's an argument that getting from "God exists" to "God's promises are trustworthy" is a matter of faith.)

This is an astonishing question that may well be closed for actually being all about personal opinion, but while it remains open, there is an important point that needs to be made, from the Bible.
God requires faith in himself if we are to be pleasing to him. Those who do not have faith in him are not pleasing to him and will not experience the reality of his love and grace towards them. Abraham was the classic example of that in the Old Testament. It was by faith that Abraham stepped out into the unknown, taking his household with him, to become God's friend, and even though he never personally inherited the land God promised, his descendants did - all because of Abraham's initial, and continually growing faith, as God made himself known to Abraham.
Read Genesis 15:1-6 & 15-17 then 18:17-19 then 26:2-5. Next, Hebrews 11:6-19.
That is how faith in God "works". It can be put as, "Commitment first - experience thereafter."
The world has it the other way around. "Experience first - commitment thereafter."
And people wonder why their supposed belief is up and down like a yo-yo, depending on their fluctuating feelings and being swayed by every wind of teaching. See James 1:6 & 1st John verses 7-9.
As for knowledge of God - that is given to those who have faith in God - by God, through his written word (Psalm 119:73-76 & 103-105 & 130 & 170), through Jesus Christ who has declared God to us (John 1:18 & 14:14-26), and according to the leading of the indwelling Holy Spirit (John 16:13-14 & 20:31). But those who dismiss these Spirit-inspired scriptures will be left to their own devices, and their own fancies, to make what they will of their own experiences and the conflicting winds of teaching that blow them about.

Abraham heard a voice and was sure a voice instructed him to go the unknown land. His faith was to trust that voice wherever it led him. His faith was not to believe that God exists for his conscience was sure God talked to him

@SoFewAgainstSoMany  Abraham already knew God existed, by faith.

he did not , he was a moon worshipper before he was called. He did not already know God existed.

Before he became Abraham was known as Abram and he was a moon worshipper , then God called him out of that idolatry and blessed the world through him. I think you could have elaborated how the knowledge of God is different from faith in God.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany  Elaboration: God gives saving faith as a gift of grace, Eph.2:8 & Acts 2:27. It is all of God so that nobody can boast of "their faith" or "their knowledge". The whole matter, for every person, is an exercise in humility before our Creator. Nobody needs to hear a 'voice' to know that humans did not create themselves. All creation testifies to the reality of God so that nobody has an excuse to say "There is no God", or "I need proof that there is a God." Thus did Abram have faith in God, who then began to reveal himself to Abram. I will leave it at that.

Frame problem.
The issue here is that you assume Faith and Knowledge are incompatible with each other. This is quite the opposite in actuality.
Well the train of thought within your question seems completely fall apart, with another question.
"Where the apostles also in violation?"
Consider that for a moment, the disciples were called and their "faith" was also backed up by direct experiences and knowledge. They knew for certain that Jesus had come back to life. Even doubting Thomas who demanded proof believed.

Here is my understanding based on the Orthodox Church

Faith and hope go together with knowledge. They are built on knowledge and lead to knowledge. For what is “not seen” is believed and hoped on the basis of what is seen. And the understanding of what is seen depends on belief and hope in what is not seen. One’s belief and hope in the ability to know, to trust his senses, his mind and the revelation of his God, are the foundations of all knowledge. (Orthodox Church of America)

This is because humanity was created to know God, not just contemplate or believe blindly that God exists.
Knowledge of God is actually the aim and goal of man's life, the purpose of his creation by God. Faith, given as a gift by God, allows you to know more and more about God.
Even the various apostles and other writers repeatedly say this. For example in the Gospel of John.

And this is eternal life, that they know Thee, the only true God, and Jesus Christ whom Thou hast sent. (John 17:3)


O Righteous Father, the world has not known Thee; and these know that Thou hast sent Me. I made known to them Thy name, and I will make it known, that the love with which Thou has loved Me may be in them, and I in them (Jn 17:25–26).

In all of his writings, the apostle Paul insists as well that the faithful have “all the riches of knowledge of God’s mystery of Christ in whom are hid all the treasures of wisdom and knowledge,” and that the “spiritual man” has “the mind of the Lord . . . the mind of Christ” (Col 2.2–3; 1 Cor 2.6–16).
We can even see it in the very beginning of Proverbs and Wisdom of Sirach.

That men might know wisdom and instruction, understand words of insight, receive instruction in wise dealing, righteousness, justice and equity, that prudence may be given to the simple, knowledge and discretion to the youth . . . The fear of the Lord is the beginning of knowledge; fools despise wisdom and instruction (Prov 1:1–7)


Many great teachings have been given to us through the Law and the Prophets and the others that followed them, and for these we should praise Israel for instruction and wisdom. Now those who read them must not only themselves understand them but must also as lovers of learning be able through both speaking and writing to help the outsiders. (Wisdom of Sirach 1:1-6)

In the spiritual tradition of the Orthodox Church, the knowledge of God and His truth is the main goal of life.

“For what meaning would there be for creation,” asks Saint Athanasius the Great (4th c.), “if man should not know God?” (On the Incarnation, Book 1).

Knowledge of God, indeed knowledge itself, according to the scriptures and the saints, is not mere “knowledge about,” the abstract knowledge of information and rational propositions, devoid of living experience. Knowledge is primarily and essentially an existential union, a combination of the spiritual man and the object of his knowledge.

“The Lord does not say that it is blessed to know something about God, but rather to possess God in oneself.” (Saint Gregory of Nyssa, On the Beatitudes, Sermon 6)

The possession of God within the mind and heart is the true knowledge of God. It comes through faith and repentance in the life of the Church. It comes essentially through the gracious purification from all sinful passions.

The growth of fear is the beginning of love, but a complete state of purity is the foundation of all divine knowledge.
He who has perfectly united his feelings to God is mystically led by Him to an understanding of His words. But without union one cannot speak about God.
The engrafted Word (Jas 1.21) perfects purity . . . and the disciple of divine knowledge is illumined. . . . but he who has not come to know God merely speculates.
Purity makes a theologian [i.e. one who knows God], who of himself grasps the teachings of the Trinity (Saint John of the Ladder, The Ladder of Divine Ascent, Step 30).

For the Orthodox Church knowledge is listed among the virtues of man. It is not limited to scientific knowledge, nor does the Orthodox Church claim that we cannot know spiritual things. It is possible to know the mysteries of God through personal relationship with Him. From this perspective religion is not a matter of personal choice, there is objective truth and genuine knowledge. This is what the saints and scriptures teach us.

For the wrath of God is revealed from heaven against all ungodliness and wickedness of men who by their wickedness suppress the truth. For what can be known of God is plain to them, because God has shown it to them. Ever since the creation of the world His invisible nature, namely His eternal power and deity, has been clearly perceived in the things that have been made. So they are without excuse; for although they knew God they did not honor Him as God or give thanks to Him, but they became futile in their thinking and their senseless minds were darkened. Claiming to be wise, they became fools, and exchanged the glory of the immortal God for images resembling mortal man or birds or animals or reptiles. Therefore God gave them up in the lusts of their hearts to impurity, to the dishonoring of their bodies among themselves, because they exchanged the truth about God for a lie and worshipped and served the creature rather than the Creator, who is blessed for ever! Amen (Rom 1:18–25).


Well answered , that knowledge and faith are separate , the knowledge of God is as a result of hope and faith in Him, upvoted.
